# Requirement for visitors to "read and understand" 10,700-word TOS/policies seems unreasonable

Tags: discussion, terms-of-service

SO and other Stack Exchange sites have been hugely beneficial to me over the years, partly because they offer fast access to high-quality answers right at the top of search results.

Recently, though, the following popup has been added to most SE sites (emphasis mine):

> By using our site, you acknowledge that you have **read and understand** our Cookie Policy, Privacy Policy, and our Terms of Service.

I imagine there's a desire for SO to cover themselves legally<sup>1</sup>, but requiring non-interacting visitors clicking through from Google to read and understand over *10,700 words* of legal terms just to view a web page seems unreasonable to me. For an average native English speaker hoping to comply with the request, this means a good ~45 minutes of reading, plus time to look up and understand any legal terminology. For non-native English speakers, the burden would be considerably higher.

To clarify, I'm not suggesting that this requirement be removed for actual account-holding users of the site -- simply that expecting every anonymous viewer to read and understand the full TOS/PP/CP seems like a policy that, if actually adhered to, would make casual use of SE sites infeasible for most visitors.

<sup>1</sup>Though if this was done to satisfy GDPR, it does not accomplish that. I am not a lawyer, but I believe GDPR requires *active* consent (simply "using our site" is not sufficient) and does not allow consent to be bundled up as a non-negotiable part of a site's terms and conditions.

Comment: That feels like just a pointless word change. Instead of "you have read and understood them", it becomes "whether you read them or not, they apply"... how would the new phrasing make the site better? I don't see it changing anything.

Comment: Have you ever read the ToS of some piece of software you installed?

Comment: @Patrice, fair point, thanks. I've edited my post to remove that suggestion and better clarify the concern with the current wording.

Comment: The ToS and Privacy Policy of most sites I've been to state that you're agreeing to them by continuing to use the site. Makoto is right that this has always been a thing, GDPR has just caused sites to make the language more prominent (in addition to other regulations where applicable).

Comment: Also, Wikipedia *does* apply their ToS to visitors who don't have accounts: *You adhere to the below Terms of Use and to the applicable community policies **when you visit our sites** or participate in our communities.*

Answer (score 12):

You've *always* had to read the ToS...this wasn't new even before the GDPR took effect.

Online agreements like this are always tough to prove out.  Saying that you've actually *read* this document is generally tough to disprove, since you "agreed" to the use of the site by continuing forward with the site's use.  Not reading something you agreed to could weaken your position should you wish to take legal action against Stack Overflow for something.

The documentary [Terms and Conditions May Apply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terms_and_Conditions_May_Apply) does a good job of covering *why* you want to read these things even if they're verbose.  It's best to bite the bullet and be sure of what you're getting yourself into.

Comment: I've taken to writing up (very short) terms for apps I make. Instead of lessening the repetitive questions I get, people just get mad when I refer them to the document they're required to read. This is to say, surprisingly, people don't seem to know that terms are _always_ "required" reading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I do think that's fine for registered users... the part I find unreasonable, though, is expecting all non-interacting visitors clicking through from Google to read an 11k-word legal document just to view a webpage (I've updated the title of my question to better reflect that). I'm not convinced this was expected on SE sites in the past, nor does it seem to be the case on other major sites like Wikipedia. Does that make sense?

Comment: @Martin:  The ToS impacts all users of the site, not just registered ones.  No, not everyone reads the terms of every site they visit, which means that they have greatly limited their knowledge of their rights on those sites.  This has ***always*** been a requirement of doing anything online.  The GDPR simply brought it back to everyone's attention, is how I'm viewing this.